# How does a Ruby method send back different amounts of variables?

Tags: ruby

When using the `RestClient` library, I can get the `response` of a `GET` like this:

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new some_url
resource.get do |response|
  # Handle response
end
```

I can also add `request` and `result` parameters:

```
resource.get do |response, request, result|
  # Handle response, request, and result
end
```

How can Ruby return one *or* multiple values like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is that when yielding to a block in Ruby, you can simply pass all values anyone would ever care about using. Then, when you create the block you can simply capture the first one, two, ... or all of the values passed into the block. It's as if all block arguments (in your case the `response`, `request`, and `result`) are optional.

```
def eat(meal)
  meal.each { |food| yield(food, 99, 100) }
  'delicious!'
end

eat([1, 2, 3]) { puts "Yum!" }
# Output:
Yum!
Yum!
Yum!
=> "delicious!"

eat([1, 2, 3]) { |a| puts "Yum! #{a}" }
# Output:
Yum! 1
Yum! 2
Yum! 3
=> "delicious!"

eat([1, 2, 3]) { |a, b, c| puts "Yum! #{a}, #{b}, #{c}" }
# Output:
Yum! 1, 99, 100
Yum! 2, 99, 100
Yum! 3, 99, 100
=> "delicious!"
```

Note how the `eat` method doesn't change, just the block you're supplying to the method. We've simply modified it to accept a couple more parameters (and do something with them).

Answer (score 3):

A method that calls a block is usually not passing varied number of arguments depending on the arity of the block (although it is possible to do it); in usual implementation, a block call passes the maximum number of arguments that a block can take. **It is rather the block that can accept a varied number of block arguments**.

Suppose `foo` takes a block, and calls it like so:

```
def foo *args, &block
  block.call(*args)
end
```

There are several cases to consider.

- When the arity of the block equals the number of arguments passed, then each block argument will receive each argument passed:

  ```
  foo(:foo, :bar){|a, b| puts "a = #{a}", "b = #{b}"}
  # => a = foo
  # => b = baz
  ```
- When the arity of the block is less than the number of arguments passed, then each block argument will receive the value of the argument in the corresponding position; extra arguments will not be passed:

  ```
  foo(:foo, :bar, :baz){|a, b| puts "a = #{a}", "b = #{b}"}
  # => a = foo
  # => b = bar
  ```
- When the arity of the block is greater than the number of arguments passed, then the extra block arguments will be assigned `nil` (unless for the case below):

  ```
  foo(:foo, :bar){|a, b, c| puts "a = #{a}", "b = #{b}", "c = #{c}"}
  # => a = foo
  # => b = bar
  # => c =
  ```
- When the arity of the block is greater than the number of arguments passed, and arrays can be destructed in a way to assign more block arguments, then destruction will be applied:

  ```
  foo([:foo, :bar, :baz]){|a, b| puts "a = #{a}", "b = #{b}"}
  # => a = foo
  # => b = bar
  ```